# Should I use smart pointers on everything and forget about classic normal pointers?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I've been using C++ for a long time and know very well about carefulness in allocating and deallocating memory, especially not forgetting to delete unused instances.

Now, I've just recently used boost and with a problem I am facing I'm forced to used smart pointers (specifically the shared_ptr) one. So, if I am going to use shared_ptr for this problem, should I use smart pointers to all my normal pointer codebase?

Comment: isn't there a performance penalty using shared_ptr?

Comment: None that you'll be able to detect if you're asking that question

Comment: @Terry: That was worded *perfectly*.

Comment: There's a performance cost to anything that makes a run-time decision, as shared_ptr does. But I agree with Terry - for most purposes, the cost is trivial in this case. And whether it's a "penalty" or not must be considered relative to the cost of alternatives - you'd have to decide when to delete the instance some other way without it.

Answer (score 18):

You should use smart pointers careful. They are not the silver bullet when considering memory management. Circular references are still an issue.

When making the class design, always think who has the ownership of an object (has the responsibility to destroy that object). Complement that with smart pointers, if necessary, but don't forget about the ownership.

Comment: +1: this is probably the most sensible advice on using smart pointers I've ever heard. Also you shouldn't get tempted to `new` everything just because smart pointers are available. Use stack allocated objects whenever you can, and smart pointers to manage the rest.

Comment: +1 for suggesting that ownership must be considered. It helps determine what memory-handling strategy to use (e.g. RAII vs. reference counting smart pointer) and how to go about implementing it.

Comment: I consider smart pointers indispensable.  Not all smart pointers are `::boost::shared_ptr`.  They don't all do reference counting.  Your comment about being careful and intentional with your ownership model is excellent advice.  But smart pointers of some variety or another are invaluable for handling whichever ownership model you want for that particular bit of data.  I do think `::boost::shared_ptr` should be used carefully and sparingly.

Comment: @Andre: I agree with you, if you can use stack allocated objects, do it.

Comment: In my experience `shared_ptr` has helped tremendously. However, there is a class of problems where resource ownership cannot be solved. Think dependency inversion and inversion of control. I've made two attempts at this problem in C++ but I don't think it can be solved.

Comment: `shared_ptr`s don't handle circular references. `weak_ptr`s do, so this shouldn't be a problem anymore

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should greatly prefer smart pointers over bare pointers for almost everything.  But that does not mean you should be using `::boost::shared_ptr` for most of those cases.  In fact I think you should use `shared_ptr` sparingly and carefully.

But for those pointers you don't use `shared_ptr` for you should be using `::std::auto_ptr` or, if you have C++0x `::std::unique_ptr`.  And if they aren't appropriate, you should find a smart pointer type that is.

Now this isn't *always* the right answer, just almost always.  Smart pointers are invaluable for tracking and freeing memory resources appropriately even in the face of exceptions or other such oddities of control flow.

There are cases in which you will need to either write your own smart pointer class or not use one.  These cases are very rare, but they exist.

For example, using a smart pointer in your own smart pointer class is probably not the right thing to be doing.  Pointing at stuff allocated in a C library would probable require a custom smart pointer that called `free` instead of delete.  Maybe you want a stretchy buffer you can call `realloc` on and don't want to use a `::std::vector` for some reason.

But generally, a smart pointer (though not usually `::boost::shared_ptr` (or in C++0x `::std::shared_ptr`)) is the right answer to your resource management problem.

Comment: You should be more careful about recommending std::auto_ptr. Because of its strange semantics on copying - violating the normal expectations for how assignment behaves - it can be a source of nasty bugs. In fact, I find it more problematic by far than naked pointers.

Comment: @Steve314 - Your and my experiences differ in this regard.  Though I do think C++0xs `::std::unique_ptr` is a much better implementation and should be preferred.  I find the compiler usually warns me when I'm doing something stupid with `auto_ptr` if I'm careful about `const` correctness and using `const` everywhere it makes sense.

Comment: You should be using **automatic** (stack-allocated0 variables for almost everything. For the rest, there are smart pointers and reference. And then, there are a bunch of other uses for bare pointers.

Comment: @Omnifarious - Most objects are either stack-allocated locals or stored in a container. IIRC, it was Stroustrup that first warned me that std::auto_ptr instances should never live in standard containers. That was all the warning I ever needed. std::auto_ptr obviously has a niche or it would never have been invented - but widespread use still seems wrong to me.

Comment: BTW - that reads like Stroustrup spoke to me personally - I'm referring to the book of course.

Comment: @Steve314 - In my opinion, that's a design flaw of the standard containers.  They should only require the ability to swap their contents, not the ability to copy.  This is a flaw that is fixed in C++0x.  The standard containers now only require the ability to move their contents, which is better than swapping anyway (but something that can only work in C++0x).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You should be using the Boost smart pointers for most everything if you have them available.  Remember this, while you can and from your comments do use pointers effectively, the person/people that come after you may not.  Using the smart pointers can and will (hopefully, can't guard against bad code) mitigate some of these issues.

I'd also recommend using [scoped_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) inside your classes even if your classes are designed well.  It'll help guard against issues the next guy could/might/most likely will introduce when faced with a naked pointer.  It'll encourage them to use them too, by example.  The last thing you want is to have to track down a memory issue because someone forgot to initialize the pointer to NULL and it's passing the if statement check.

Comment: And if you don't have them available, at least use some sort of smart pointer.

Comment: @Eclipse yes, RAII all the way.

Comment: I would recommend using shared_ptr only when you specifically need it, and that should be rarely.  But yes, some form of smart pointer, definitely.

Comment: Hmmm - do you think std::map uses smart pointers to point to nodes in its data structure? Do you think the standard and Boost libraries provide the only data structures that are ever needed? If you answered no to both of these questions, you have a reason for using naked pointers. Obviously, coding your own container templates is an unusual thing, but it isn't unheard of. Even the standard libraries are reinventions of earlier libraries (e.g. in other languages) that did much the same thing - there can be good reasons to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @wheaties: I don't understand that argument. Except for calling `delete` at the right moment automagically, they are still *pointers*.

Comment: @wheaties - I do not think naked pointers should generally be used.  In fact, in answer to @Steve314's question, I would implement map using a type like `::std::auto_ptr` for pointing at child nodes.  But I do not think `::boost::shared_ptr` should be used very often.

Comment: @wheaties - Omnifarious didn't recommend naked pointers. Even I only said that there are exceptional special cases. Agreed - some people cannot use pointers correctly. But *someone* had to write the standard libraries, so clearly there are some people who *can* use naked pointers correctly. And without that use of naked pointers, there wouldn't be a standard library. So it's exception, yes, but never say never.

Comment: @Omnifarious - if you'd use std::auto_ptr for pointing to child nodes, wouldn't your data structure be invalidated with nodes being deleted every time you tried to search the tree (thus working with local copies of those std::auto_ptr instances). Seems to me that avoiding this problem would be easier if you just used naked pointers, though using shared_ptr would be safe.

Comment: @Steve314 - Actually, in that case, I would use bare pointers inside the traversal routines and make a temporary copy of the bare pointer inside `auto_ptr` using the `get` method.  So, yes, I'd use a naked pointer in implementing map, but not in the data structure itself, only in the algorithms that traverse that structure.  Though the iterator (which needs to keep a stack of something) would be an interesting case.

Comment: @Omnifarious - I'm not convinced. About the only benefit I can see to using std::auto_ptr for a tree data structure is you can delete the whole tree (or a subtree) by deleting the root and letting the rest happen automatically. This is trivial WRT all the other code you'd write for a data structure. Bear in mind, when deleting an item from a binary tree for example, you will be deleting a node that may have children still linked - but you don't want to delete those children, since you'll be relinking them back into the tree.

Comment: @Omnifarious and @Steve314 might I suggest http://chat.stackoverflow.com/ to iron out your differences?  Communications would be faster and easier for both of you.

Comment: @wheaties - I never did like chat programs. Still, you're probably right, except that I think we're finished anyway by now.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not use smart pointers for everything.
What you should consider whenever typing `new`:

> - What is the lifetime of this object?
> - Which object **owns** it?
> - How is that object going to manage its lifetime?

Sometimes the solution is a smart pointer but also *the* lazy answer. "I don't want to be bothered to work out which object owns this pointer and what its lifetime should be hence I'll make it a shared_pointer!"

The important question is; *What is managing the lifetime of this object?*, the answer can be a smart pointer, but oftentimes, it doesn't need to be.

Answer (score -1):

No. It depends on what you're doing.

- Smart pointers have a performance overhead. In desktop applications, this is typically not a concern, but depending on what you do, it might be.
- Smart pointers will not work right if you have reference cycles, i.e. A pointing to B and B pointing to A, or even something pointing to itself.

Comment: shared & weak ptr work fine in a cycle, what smart pointer are you referring to when you say it will not work

Comment: @Omnifarious - they don't have a *big* performance overhead, but they do have an overhead. For example, reference counted smart pointers have overheads for the counting. Insignificant for most purposes, but still an overhead.

Comment: @Steve314 - `::std::auto_ptr` has no overhead whatsoever.  So a blanket statement that smart pointers have a performance overhead is false.  `::boost::shared_ptr` does have a very small overhead, it's true, but that's not the only kind of smart pointer around.

Comment: @Omnifarious - you made the blanket statement that smart pointers have no performance overhead, which is false. I could have been more careful with my wording, but my excuse is that std::auto_ptr isn't smart - in fact it's pretty stupid.

Comment: "_Smart pointers will not work right if you have reference cycles_" no, they work right in every case: the objects will not be destroyed